# YouTube search operators in API call?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

How can I use `OR` to search for the term in either `title` or `tag` or `description`?

```
&q=%23%23"iraqi food" OR title:"israeli food" OR description:"iranian food"

// %23%23"iraqi food" = ##Tagname
```

This only brings results of `iraqi food`. I've also used some variants (just played around, as I counldn't find any examples.), but they didn't work either.

[List of search operators](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2685977?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) Returns a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request.  By default, a search result set identifies matching video, channel, and playlist resources, but you can also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource.

> q
>  string 
>  The q parameter specifies the query term to search for.
>
> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to
>   exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of
>   several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching
>   either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to
>   boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either
>   "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to
>   boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be
>   URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value
>   for the pipe character is %7C.

**answer**:  You can not specific request title tag or description.  It just searches for you.  the best you can do is `&q=iraqi|food` which will give you results with either Iraqi or food